# texture paint isnt working in certain places

Tags: texturing

I've been working on an axe, the 3D model is complete and I'm working on texturing. Most of it textured no problem but there is little bits that wont texture whatever I do. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed It I just sighlighted the faces that had the bits of texcture missing and projected them from view and moved it to part of the image with the same colour